# can not find module node-sass with angular 7

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I cloned an old project of mine which I wish to revive.
The project is running with angluar 7 and ionic 4.
When running:
`npm run build`
I am encountering with the issue of  `Error: Cannot find module 'node-sass'`
Now the environment is fresh new. with node 16.10.0 and npm 7 (those dependencies are because of the old project)
Trying to follow other questions that instruct me to install node-sass, just lead to incompatible versions.
Any suggestions?